# Understand disaster model in PyMC

Tags: pymc

I start learning PyMC and strungle to understand the very first tutorial´s example.

```html
disasters_array =   \
     np.array([ 4, 5, 4, 0, 1, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 3, 3, 4, 0, 2, 6,
                   3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 1, 4, 4, 1, 5, 5, 3, 4, 2, 5,
                   2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0,
                   1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1,
                   0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2,
                   3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 4,
                   0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
switchpoint = DiscreteUniform('switchpoint', lower=0, upper=110, doc='Switchpoint[year]')
early_mean = Exponential('early_mean', beta=1.)
late_mean = Exponential('late_mean', beta=1.)
```

I don´t understand why early_mean and late_mean is modeled as stochastic variable following exponential distribution with rate = 1. My intuition is that they should be deterministic calculated using disasters_array and switchpoint variable e.g.

```html
@deterministic(plot=False)
def early_mean(s=switchpoint):
    return sum(disasters_array[:(s-1)])/(s-1)

@deterministic(plot=False)
def late_mean(s=switchpoint):
    return sum(disasters_array[s:])/s
```

Answer (score 0):

`disasters_array` are the data generated by a Poisson process, under the assumptions of this model. `late_mean` and `early_mean` are the parameters associated with this process, depending on when in the time series they occurred. The true values of the parameters are unknown, so they are specified as stochastic variables. Deterministic objects are only for nodes that are *completely* determined by the values of their parents.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `early_mean` and `late_mean` stochastics as model parameters, and the `Exponential` as the prior distribution for these parameters.  In the version of the model here, the deterministic `r` and likelihood `D` lead to posteriors on `early_mean` and `late_mean` through MCMC sampling.